# How to connect to dynamodb from lambda

Tags: java, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I'm trying to connect to DynamoDB from a java lambda function, it works locally with aws profile ~/.aws/credentials. How will this work in AWS environment as I can't set profile details in the credentials file?

```
private static AmazonDynamoDB dynamoClient = AmazonDynamoDBClientBuilder.standard()
        .withEndpointConfiguration(
                new AwsClientBuilder.EndpointConfiguration("https://dynamodb.us-west-2.amazonaws.com", "us-west-2"))
        .withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider()).build();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default, your function uses its role in order to run and make API calls.
In this case, you set the `.withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())` which means that Lambda is looking at the `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` (or `AWS_ACCESS_KEY`) and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` (or `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`) environment variables.

So your 2 options are:

1. Remove `.withCredentials(new EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider())` and configure a proper role to the function that has permissions that match your function's logic.
2. Provide `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_KEY` to your function.

Unless you have a really good reason, go with option 1.